# Twilio "Could not find Address with sid ... to satisfy Local Address requirement"

Tags: php, twilio

I'm trying to use the Twilio API to buy a phone number with a "Local" address requirement on behalf of a customer using the "Connect" API.

The purchase request looks like this:

```
$twilio = new \Twilio\Rest\Client($customerConnectedSid, env('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'));

$numberRes = $twilio->incomingPhoneNumbers->create([
    'phoneNumber' => $numberString,
    'addressSid' => $user->company->twilio_address_sid,
]);
```

The error I get back from Twilio is:

> [HTTP 400] Unable to create record: Could not find Address with sid AD*** for account AC*** to satisfy Local Address requirement

I don't know why it can't "find" that address because both the `accountSid` and `sid` match in the response from:

```
$twilio->addresses->read([], 100)
```

So clearly the address exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think I just figured it out, but I'm going to leave the question up anyway in case someone else encounters it.

The error message is just bad.

It **can** "find" the address, but it doesn't *satisfy* the local address requirement.

Make sure the address is actually for the region where the phone number is.